# Cobertura Branch coverage say N/A

Tags: ant, cobertura

i have followed every steps how to do the cobertura Report.
At the End of the Report it say Branch Coverage as N/A and line Coverage as 100%
Coverage Report][image: []1] and  [image: condition File]![[]2]

please Verify wheather the report was correct or not

Comment: @ vinod: Please post relevant sections from build.xml.  From the description it appears the instrumentation, data collection and reporting uses different instrumented jars jars or .ser files that are not correct.

Comment: below is the classpath of cobertura.i am using .ser file which came after stopping tomcat 
<path id="cobertura.class.path">
  <pathelement location="D:/Share/cobertura-1.9.4.1/cobertura.jar" />
  <pathelement location="D:/Share/cobertura-1.9.4.1/lib/asm-3.0.jar" />
  <pathelement location="D:/Share/cobertura-1.9.4.1/lib/asm-tree-3.0.jar" />
  <pathelement location="D:/Share/cobertura-1.9.4.1/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar" />
  <pathelement location="D:/Share/cobertura-1.9.4.1/lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar" />
  </path>